# Rsyslog stopped processing imfile

Tags: logging, rsyslog

My rsyslog was processing the file of /var/log/pihole/pihole.log without any issue when I added it.  However, on reboot it started complaining that it is not able to reach the remote server though it is able to connect to it.

````
    ● rsyslog.service - System Logging Service
       Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/rsyslog.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
       Active: active (running) since Mon 2023-01-23 11:35:12 +08; 6min ago
         Docs: man:rsyslogd(8)
               https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/
     Main PID: 410 (rsyslogd)
        Tasks: 5 (limit: 2059)
       CGroup: /system.slice/rsyslog.service
               └─410 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n -iNONE
    
    Jan 23 11:35:11 ph systemd[1]: Starting System Logging Service...
    Jan 23 11:35:12 ph rsyslogd[410]: imuxsock: Acquired UNIX socket '/run/systemd/journal/syslog' (fd 3) from systemd.  [v8.1901.0]
    Jan 23 11:35:12 ph rsyslogd[410]:  [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.1901.0" x-pid="410" x-info="https://www.rsyslog.com"] start
    **Jan 23 11:35:12 ph rsyslogd[410]: cannot connect to 192.168.1.75:514: Network is unreachable [v8.1901.0 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2027 ]**
    Jan 23 11:35:12 ph rsyslogd[410]: action 'action-13-builtin:omfwd' suspended (module 'builtin:omfwd'), retry 0. There should be messages before this one giving the reason for suspension. [v8.1901.0 try 
    **Jan 23 11:35:12 ph rsyslogd[410]: cannot connect to 192.168.1.75:514: Network is unreachable [v8.1901.0 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2027 ]**
    Jan 23 11:35:12 ph rsyslogd[410]: action 'action-13-builtin:omfwd' suspended (module 'builtin:omfwd'), next retry is Mon Jan 23 11:35:42 2023, retry nbr 0. There should be messages before this one givin
    Jan 23 11:35:12 ph systemd[1]: Started System Logging Service.
    Jan 23 11:35:53 ph rsyslogd[410]: action 'action-13-builtin:omfwd' resumed (module 'builtin:omfwd') [v8.1901.0 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2359 ]```

Here we can see that the connection is still established
````

```
root@ph:/home/pi# netstat -antulp | grep 514
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.8:49954       192.168.1.75:514        ESTABLISHED 410/rsyslogd
```

These are the lines in rsyslog.conf file.

```
# tail -n 11 /etc/rsyslog.conf
#These lines are to monitor PiHole
$ModLoad imfile
$InputFileName /var/log/pihole/pihole.log 
$InputFileTag pihole
$InputFileStateFile stat-pihole
$InputFileSeverity info
$InputFileFacility local6
$InputRunFileMonitor

#This line is to send the logs to SIEM
*.* @@192.168.1.75:514
```

I expect the logs of "/var/log/pihole/pihole.log " to be piped to SIEM. However, when I restart rsyslog that shows up in SIEM. It is just that pihole.log contents is not longer being processed by rsyslog.

Comment: The message `action 'action-13-builtin:omfwd' resumed` means that it did successfully connect. If you are no longer getting logs from the file remotely, it may be that the file got renamed (by pihole or log rotate), and rsyslog is still reading the old file. You should probably convert to new syntax `module(load="builtin:omfile" ...)` and `action(type="omfile"...)` because [this](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/imfile.html#mode) says `$ModLoad` implies polling, instead of inotify.

Comment: @meuh, I was able to see pihole was still writing to the same file with tail -f command, but somehow rsyslog was not reading from it. The way I got to fix it is  

1. Stop the service of both pihole and rsyslog. 
2. Delete the /var/log/pihole/pihole.log 
3. Start the service of pihole and ryslog.

Comment: Is there a way to mark this question as resolved?

Comment: To resolve the question, post your own answer based on your comment above, then accept it by clicking the tick mark. You may need to wait a few hours before you are allowed to tick the answer.